# Copy used range to text file

Tags: excel, vba, copy, range

I want to:

- Copy the used range of a sheet called "Kommentar"
- Create a ".txt" file ("Kommentar.txt") in the same directory as ThisWorkbook
- Paste the previously copied used range
- Save the ".txt" file

I have:

```
Sub CreateAfile()

Dim pth As String
pth = ThisWorkbook.path
Dim fs As Object
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim a As Object
Set a = fs.CreateTextFile(pth & "\Kommentar.txt", True)
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Kommentar")

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = sh.UsedRange
a.WriteLine (rng)
a.Close

End Sub
```

I get

> run-time error '13' Mismatch

In line `a.WriteLine (rng)` the function doesn't accept range to be written.

Comment: Writeln with string parameter .., you have to get value cell by cell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your range is probably made up of several cells, you have to loop through them to get all the text into a string variable. If you use a Variant variable you can copy the values and automatically get an array with the correct dimensions of all the data in the cells, then loop it and copy the text:

```
Function GetTextFromRangeText(ByVal poRange As Range) As String
    Dim vRange As Variant
    Dim sRet As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    If Not poRange Is Nothing Then

        vRange = poRange

        For i = LBound(vRange) To UBound(vRange)
            For j = LBound(vRange, 2) To UBound(vRange, 2)
                sRet = sRet & vRange(i, j)
            Next j
            sRet = sRet & vbCrLf
        Next i
    End If

    GetTextFromRangeText = sRet
End Function
```

Call the function in your code by replacing the `a.WriteLine (rng)` line with the following:

```
Dim sRange As String
sRange = GetTextFromRangeText(rng)
Call a.WriteLine(sRange)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure you can do that. I believe you would have to write it out line by line.

Here is an alternative option.

Rather than use the FSO, you could just try saving the sheet as a .txt file.
Here's some sample code.
Credit should goto http://goo.gl/mEHVx

```
Option Explicit

'Copy the contents of a worksheet, and save it as a new workbook as a .txt file
Sub Kommentar_Tab()
Dim wbSource As Workbook
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim wbDest As Workbook
Dim fName As String

'References
Set wbSource = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Kommentar")
Set wbDest = Workbooks.Add

'Copy range on original sheet
'Using usedrange can be risky and may return the wrong result.
wsSource.UsedRange.Copy

'Save in new workbook
wbDest.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Get file name and location
fName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Kommentar.txt"

'Save new tab delimited file
wbDest.SaveAs fName, xlText

wbDest.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `yourRange` is the range you want to copy as string.

1. Use `yourRange`. Copy to copy it.
2. After you copied it, Excel saves the text value to the clipboard. Cells in a row separated by tabs, and every row ends with an enter. You can use DataObject's `GetFromClipboard` and `GetText` method to save it to a string variable.
3. Use `CreateTextFile` to save it to a file.

Answer (score 0):

@xwhitelight gives a good outline. Thanks. But I needed to supply details to myself to accomplish my own task and thought I'd share.

First, a `Reference` to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` and another to `Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library` are required.

The coding details I added to produce an output file follow.

Note that `textfilename` is the *fully-qualified* **name** of the output file that contains the spreadsheet range.

Note that `textfilename` is opened in the last line of the `sub`, which isn't necessary, but it's reassuring to SEE what the file contains. Of course, the `MsgBox` is also unnecessary.

```
Sub turnRangeIntoTextFile(rg As Range, textfilename As String)

  Dim textFile as TextStream

  Dim fs As FileSystemObject
  Dim myData As DataObject

  Set myData = New DataObject
  Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  rg.Copy
  myData.GetFromClipboard
  MsgBox myData.GetText ' reassurance (see what I got)

  Set textFile = fs.CreateTextFile(textfilename, True)
  textFile.WriteLine (myData.GetText)
  textFile.Close

  CreateObject("Shell.Application").Open (textfilename)

End Sub
```